# What is the significance of the tale narrated by Nadir to the muezzin Marwan in the short story 'Time, as It Evaporates…'?

Tags: short-stories, french-language, jean-claude-dunyach

In the French science fiction short story "Le temps, en s'évaporant…" by Jean-Claude Dunyach, translated into English by Jean-Louis Trudel as "Time, as It Evaporates…", there is a conversation between the sponge-fisher Nadir and the [muezzin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muezzin) Marwan. Since Nadir can no longer leave the bubble of time in which the town exists to go sponge-fishing, he has become a storyteller in order to earn a living.

Nadir narrates to Marwan one of his tales, about a God of the desert who sought immortality by surrounding himself with tall walls defended by guards in order that Death may never find him. But, when the God realized that he had diminished himself immensely in this process and had become prisoner in his own labyrinth, it was already too late for him, and he remains there to this day, trapped and immortal.

**Why does Nadir choose this tale to narrate to Marwan?**

Nadir claims that his stories have no basis in morality, and are only intended to amuse and entertain his listeners. But, he and Marwan have established through their conversation that they hold opposite views on what ought to guide a person in their lives: Marwan believes that one must continue to follow the religious dictums as everyone did before the temporal disaster struck, whereas Nadir only wishes to spend the rest of his life in relative comfort, certain that he will be destroyed with the rest of the entire Universe as the time bubble in which their town resides slowly collapses. Surely Nadir intends to drive home a point with his tale, and not just impress Marwan with his storytelling skills. What is Nadir trying to convey through the medium of his tale about the desert God who sought immortality and found it?